# How to get Java USA to correctly read Excel files in Spanish

Tags: java, excel

I have written a Java program (in USA) that reads and writes Excel files. The package includes a set of example Excel files (USA).  Spanish language users get error when reading these Excel example files because of confusion about "." and "," in numerical files.  How can I program so that Java determines the users default language and accounts for this in using Excel.

Comment: Which API are using for reading the excel files?  My best guess is that you somehow have to set the locale or the number format which the api/library uses when reading the files.

Comment: “Spanish language users get error” It would be useful to include the text (and stack trace!) of that error in your question.  Without it, we don’t even know what code is causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just create `NumberFormat` using specific **locale** for Spanish. 
Here I create locale for Spanish from Spain (es-ES) and parse the number as String.

```
NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getInstance(new Locale("es", "ES"));
Number number = nf.parse(numberString);
```